# Nginx Ingress Controller - Failed Calling Webhook

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, kubeadm

I set up a k8s cluster using kubeadm (v1.18) on an Ubuntu virtual machine.
Now I need to add an Ingress Controller. I decided for nginx (but I'm open for other solutions). I installed it according to the [docs](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/), section "bare-metal":

`kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-0.31.1/deploy/static/provider/baremetal/deploy.yaml`

The installation seems fine to me:

`kubectl get all -n ingress-nginx`

```
NAME                                            READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
pod/ingress-nginx-admission-create-b8smg        0/1     Completed   0          8m21s
pod/ingress-nginx-admission-patch-6nbjb         0/1     Completed   1          8m21s
pod/ingress-nginx-controller-78f6c57f64-m89n8   1/1     Running     0          8m31s

NAME                                         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
service/ingress-nginx-controller             NodePort    10.107.152.204   <none>        80:32367/TCP,443:31480/TCP   8m31s
service/ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP   10.110.191.169   <none>        443/TCP                      8m31s

NAME                                       READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/ingress-nginx-controller   1/1     1            1           8m31s

NAME                                                  DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/ingress-nginx-controller-78f6c57f64   1         1         1       8m31s

NAME                                       COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
job.batch/ingress-nginx-admission-create   1/1           2s         8m31s
job.batch/ingress-nginx-admission-patch    1/1           3s         8m31s
```

However, when trying to apply a custom Ingress, I get the following error:

`Error from server (InternalError): error when creating "yaml/xxx/xxx-ingress.yaml": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io": Post https://ingress-nginx-controller-admission.ingress-nginx.svc:443/extensions/v1beta1/ingresses?timeout=30s: Temporary Redirect`

Any idea what could be wrong?

I suspected DNS, but other NodePort services are working as expected and DNS works within the cluster.

The only thing I can see is that I don't have a default-http-backend which is mentioned in the [docs here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/#over-a-nodeport-service). However, this seems normal in my case, according to [this thread](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/680#issuecomment-365524769).

Last but not least, I tried as well the [installation with manifests](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-manifests/) (after removing ingress-nginx namespace from previous installation) and the [installation via Helm chart](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/). It has the same result.

I'm pretty much a beginner on k8s and this is my playground-cluster. So I'm open to alternative solutions as well, as long as I don't need to set up the whole cluster from scratch.

**Update:**
With "applying custom Ingress", I mean:
`kubectl apply -f <myIngress.yaml>`

Content of myIngress.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /someroute/fittingmyneeds
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          serviceName: some-service
          servicePort: 5000
```

Comment: What do you mean by `when trying to apply a custom Ingress`? What exactly is your custom Ingress?

Comment: @OhHiMark: I mean `kubectl apply -f <myIngress.yaml>. I added the information in the original post.

Comment: Looks like your Ingress.yaml is misconfigured. I see you are trying to use the rewrite annotation but there is no capture group defined. [Here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/) you will find an explained example of how to use that annotation. Please take a look and let me know if that helps.

Comment: any solution without deleting ValidatingWebhookConfiguration?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure if this helps this late, but might it be, that your cluster was behind proxy? Because in that case you have to have `no_proxy` configured correctly. Specifically, it has to include `.svc,.cluster.local` otherwise validation webhook requests such as `https://ingress-nginx-controller-admission.ingress-nginx.svc:443/extensions/v1beta1/ingresses?timeout=30s` will be routed via proxy server (note that **.svc** in the URL).

I had exactly this issue and adding `.svc` into no_proxy variable helped. You can try this out quickly by modifying `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml` file which will in turn automatically recreate your kubernetes api server pod.

This is not the case just for ingress validation, but also for other things that might refer URL in your cluster ending with `.svc` or `.namespace.svc.cluster.local` (i.e. see this [bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1467776))

Comment: And BTW - I would not disable validation webhook for ingress resources. They are there for reason and can prevent your controller going completely down by someone applying corrupted ingress (not in terms of syntax, but runtime issues). Then all applications behind this ingress controller will become unavailable.

Comment: Indeed, I am behind a proxy. Your solutions seems clean and works. Thank you!

Comment: @petermicuch, kindly please elaborate more on how todo that. I tried add --> - --no_proxy=".svc" , restart the master node result on my kubectl can not access it.

Answer (score 95):

Another option you have is to remove the Validating Webhook entirely:

`kubectl delete -A ValidatingWebhookConfiguration ingress-nginx-admission`

I found I had to do that on [another issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62044090/2286960), but the workaround/solution works here as well.

This isn't the best answer; the best answer is to figure out why this doesn't work. But at some point, you live with workarounds.

I'm installing on Docker for Mac, so I used the `cloud` rather than `baremetal` version:

`kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.34.1/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml`

Comment: `kubectl delete -A ValidatingWebhookConfiguration ingress-nginx-admission` resolved it for me on minikube 1.12 with k8s 1.18.

Comment: @Patrick Gardella this seems to be the practical solution for many people, as demonstrated by the many upvotes on your related post https://stackoverflow.com/a/62044090/1549918. I'm not even sure it's only a workaround,.

Comment: Instead of deleting the Admission Webhook a more practical solution is to allow in the firewall all nodes to communicate with port 8443. https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/  - "In case Network policies or additional firewalls, please allow access to port 8443."

Comment: I really hate upvoting this. But it worked.

Answer (score 62):

In my case I'd mixed the installations up.
I resolved the issue by executing the following steps:

```
$ kubectl get validatingwebhookconfigurations
```

I iterated through the list of configurations received from the above steps and deleted the configuration using

```
$ `kubectl delete validatingwebhookconfigurations [configuration-name]`
```

Comment: any solution without deleting ValidatingWebhookConfiguration?

Comment: Thanks! I my case, `ingress-nginx-admission` had another name => nginx-ingress-nginx-admission. Got it with `kubectl get validatingwebhookconfigurations`

Comment: I did the mess to install a second ingress and it just mess up everything. When I removed the second ingress the validatingwebhookconfigurations was keeped in the cluster, so this solution solved my problem

Answer (score 27):

In my case I didn't need to delete the ValidatingWebhookConfiguration. The issue was that I was using a private cluster on GCP version **1.17.14-gke.1600**. For gke private clusters, the validatingwebhook tries to access master node API at port 8443. In my case it was failing because I did not have that port allowed at the firewall. So the current workaround for that, as [recommended by Google itself](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters#add_firewall_rules) (but very poorly documented) is adding a Firewall rule on GCP, that will allow inbound (Ingress) TCP requests to your master node at port 8443, so that the other nodes within the cluster can reach the master for validatingwebhook API running on it with that very port.

As to how to create the rule, this is how I did it:

1. Went to [Firewall Rules](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/firewalls/list) and added a new one.
2. At the field **Network** I selected the VPC from which my cluster is.
3. **Direction of traffic** I set as `Ingress`
4. **Action on match** to `Allow`
5. **Targets** to `Specified target tags`
6. The  **Target tags** can be found on the master node details in a property called **Network tags**. To find it, I opened a new window, went to my cluster node pools, found the master node pool. Then entered one of the nodes to look for the Virtual Machine details. There I found **Network Tags**. Copied its value and went back to the Firewall Rule form.
7. Pasted the copied network tag to the tag field
8. At **Protocols and ports**, checked the `Specified protocols and ports`
9. Then checked **TCP** and placed 8443
10. Saved the rule and applied the manifest again.

> NOTE: Most threads out there will say it's the port 9443. It may work. But I first attempted 8443 since it was reported to work on [this thread](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/5401#issuecomment-617006161). It worked for me so I didn't even try 9443.

Comment: Thank you for your great explanation! I encountered this problem with our private prod GKE cluster. I should notice that i only added the port 8443 to make it work.

Comment: Same for me. In my case, I had to open a security group on my custom install at AWS.

Comment: Super helpful, thanks! I also only added port 8443 and it worked. You might want to add some info about what source to select when creating the firewall rule (I used the entire block I also specified in --master-ipv4-cidr= when creating the cluster).

Comment: This is the correct answer. Better filter source for master-CIDR.

Comment: Thank you, Mauricio, your instruction helped me a lot. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 22):

Might be because of a previous nginx-ingress-controller configuration.
You can try to run the following command -

```
kubectl delete -A ValidatingWebhookConfiguration ingress-nginx-admission
```

Comment: Thanks. Your comment probably explains my situation. I managed to install some older ingress controller version thanks to some non-update documentation (or not paying attention).

Comment: This worked for me. I had a previous installation of ingress-nginx, then updated docker and had to reinstall the ingress-nginx, after that I was getting the error, but with this command I was able to get rid of the previous nginx-ingress controller configuration

Answer (score 12):

I've solved this issue. The problem was that you use Kubernetes version 1.18, but the ValidatingWebhookConfiguration in current ingress-Nginx uses the oldest API; see the doc:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/#prerequisites

*Ensure that the Kubernetes cluster is at least as new as v1.16 (to use admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1), or v1.9 (to use admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1).*

And in current  yaml :

```
 # Source: ingress-nginx/templates/admission-webhooks/validating-webhook.yaml
    # before changing this value, check the required kubernetes version
    # https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/#prerequisites
apiVersion: admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1
```

and in rules :

```
apiVersions:
          - v1beta1
```

So you need to change it on v1 :

```
apiVersion: admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1
```

and add rule -v1 :

```
apiVersions:
          - v1beta1
          - v1
```

After you change it and redeploy -your custom ingress service will deploy sucessfull

Comment: In order to know what version of `admissionregistration.k8s.io` is compatible with your setup, use `kubectl api-versions | grep admissionregistration`

Comment: this is great, has saved me after way too long trying to troubleshoot. Thanks Oleg.

Comment: That seems to have solved my problem mate. Thanks!

Comment: Oleg, in "or v1.9 (to use admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1)", did you mean to write v1.19? v1.24 seems to be the newest K8s version as I'm writing this.

Answer (score 9):

Finally, I managed to run Ingress Nginx properly by changing the way of installation. I still don't understand why the previous installation didn't work, but I'll share nevertheless the solution along with some more insights into the original problem.

**Solution**

Uninstall ingress nginx: Delete the ingress-nginx namespace. This does not remove the validating webhook configuration - delete this one manually. Then install MetalLB and install ingress nginx again. I now used the version from the Helm stable repo. Now everything works as expected. Thanks to Long on the kubernetes slack channel!

**Some more insights into the original problem**

The yamls provided by the [installation guide](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-0.32.0/deploy/static/provider/baremetal/deploy.yaml) contain a ValidatingWebHookConfiguration:

```
apiVersion: admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ValidatingWebhookConfiguration
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-2.0.3
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.32.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
  namespace: ingress-nginx
webhooks:
  - name: validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io
    rules:
      - apiGroups:
          - extensions
          - networking.k8s.io
        apiVersions:
          - v1beta1
        operations:
          - CREATE
          - UPDATE
        resources:
          - ingresses
    failurePolicy: Fail
    clientConfig:
      service:
        namespace: ingress-nginx
        name: ingress-nginx-controller-admission
        path: /extensions/v1beta1/ingresses
```

Validation is performed whenever I create or update an ingress (the content of my ingress.yaml doesn't matter). The validation failed, because when calling the service, the response is a Temporary Redirect. I don't know why.
The corresponding service is:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-2.0.3
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.32.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx-controller-admission
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: https-webhook
      port: 443
      targetPort: webhook
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
```

The pod matching the selector comes from this deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-2.0.3
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.32.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
      app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  minReadySeconds: 0
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    spec:
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      containers:
        - name: controller
          image: quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.32.0
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          lifecycle:
            preStop:
              exec:
                command:
                  - /wait-shutdown
          args:
            - /nginx-ingress-controller
            - --election-id=ingress-controller-leader
            - --ingress-class=nginx
            - --configmap=ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx-controller
            - --validating-webhook=:8443
            - --validating-webhook-certificate=/usr/local/certificates/cert
            - --validating-webhook-key=/usr/local/certificates/key
          securityContext:
            capabilities:
              drop:
                - ALL
              add:
                - NET_BIND_SERVICE
            runAsUser: 101
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
          env:
            - name: POD_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: POD_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 1
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 3
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 1
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 3
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
            - name: https
              containerPort: 443
              protocol: TCP
            - name: webhook
              containerPort: 8443
              protocol: TCP
          volumeMounts:
            - name: webhook-cert
              mountPath: /usr/local/certificates/
              readOnly: true
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 90Mi
      serviceAccountName: ingress-nginx
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 300
      volumes:
        - name: webhook-cert
          secret:
            secretName: ingress-nginx-admission
```

Something in this validation chain goes wrong. Would be interesting to know, what and why, but I can continue working with my MetalLB solution. Note that this solution does not contain a validating webhook at all.

Answer (score 6):

On a baremetal cluster, I disabled the `admissionWebhooks` during the Helm3 install:

```
kubectl create ns ingress-nginx

helm install [RELEASE_NAME] ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx -n ingress-nginx --set controller.admissionWebhooks.enabled=false
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case, it was the AWS EKS module, which now comes with harden security group.  but nginx-ingress requires the cluster to communicate with the ingress controller so I have to whitelist below port in the node security group

```
  node_security_group_additional_rules = {
    cluster_to_node = {
      description      = "Cluster to ingress-nginx webhook"
      protocol         = "-1"
      from_port        = 8443
      to_port          = 8443
      type             = "ingress"
      source_cluster_security_group = true
    }
  }
```

[input_node_security_group_additional_rules](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks#input_node_security_group_additional_rules)

Comment: Can you please share how to do this from AWS UI? I do not see type as ingress there and cutom protocol does not allow port.

Comment: from AWS UI, you can click on any worker node, security -> security group and open the desired port.

Comment: If anybody is following the Official guide of Nginx Ingress (https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#aws) and using Terraform, this is the solution.

Answer (score 3):

If using terraform and helm disable the Validating Webhook

```
resource "helm_release" "nginx_ingress" {

...

  set {
    name  = "controller.admissionWebhooks.enabled"
    value = "false"
  }

...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this error.  Basically I have a script installing the nginx controller with helm; the script then immediately installs an application that uses ingress, also with helm.  That app install failed, just the ingress part.

Solution was to wait 60s after the install of the nginx, to give the WebAdmissionHook time to come up and be ready.

Answer (score 1):

To add a terraform example for GCP, extending @mauricio

```html
resource "google_container_cluster" "primary" {
...
}


resource "google_compute_firewall" "validate_nginx" {
  project = local.project
  name    = "validate-nginx"
  network = google_compute_network.vpc.name
  allow {
    protocol = "tcp"
    ports    = ["8443"]
  }
  direction = "INGRESS"
  source_ranges = [google_container_cluster.primary.private_cluster_config[0].master_ipv4_cidr_block]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me was to increase the timeout while waiting for ingress to come up.

Answer (score 0):

I was bringing up a cluster with a known-good configuration and another had been created just last week in essentially the same way.  And my error message was a little more specific about what failed in the webhook :

```
│ Error: Failed to create Ingress
'auth-system/alertmanager-oauth2-proxy' 
because: Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook
"validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io": Post
"https://nginx-nginx-ingress-controller-controller-admission.ingress-nginx.svc:443/networking/v1beta1/ingresses?timeout=10s":
x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

It turns out that in my many configs, one of them had a typo in the DNS names input to nginx creation.  So nginx thought it had one domain name, but it got a certificate for a slightly different dns name, which caused the validating web hook to fail.

The solution was not to delete the hook, but to address the underlying config problem in nginx dns so that it matched its X.509 certificate domain.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `v1` instead of `v1beta1` in `deploy.yaml`

Answer (score 0):

**This is a solution for those using GKE cluster.**

I tested two ways to fix this issue.

- Terraform
- GCP Console

**Terraform**

```
resource "google_compute_firewall" "validate-nginx" {
  project = "${YOUR_PROJECT_ID}"
  name    = "access-master-to-validatenginx"
  network = "${YOUR_NETWORK}"
  
  allow {
    protocol = "tcp"
    ports    = ["8443"]
  }

  target_tags   = ["${NODE_NETWORK_TAG}"]
  source_ranges = ["${CONTROL_PLANE_ADDRESS_RANGE}"]
}
```

**GCP Console**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have solve this by removing ValidatingWebhookConfiguration which is created by previous ingress-nginx deployment in default namespace. ValidatingWebhookConfiguration must be exist one in default namespace otherwise will conflict each other. plz check below:

Error from server (InternalError): error when creating "ingress.yaml": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io": failed to call webhook: Post "https://sr-nginx-ingress-nginx-controller-admission.ingress-nginx.svc:443/networking/v1/ingresses?timeout=10s": service "sr-nginx-ingress-nginx-controller-admission" not found

pradip@linux:~$ kubectl get -A ValidatingWebhookConfiguration
NAME                               WEBHOOKS   AGE
aks-node-validating-webhook        1          11d
ingress-nginx-admission            1          3h47m
sr-nginx-ingress-nginx-admission   1          11d

pradip@linux:~$ kubectl delete ValidatingWebhookConfiguration sr-nginx-ingress-nginx-admission
validatingwebhookconfiguration.admissionregistration.k8s.io "sr-nginx-ingress-nginx-admission" deleted

pradip@linux:~$ kubectl apply -f ingress.yaml
ingress.networking.k8s.io/ingress-reddit-app created

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was iptables not allowing 8443 through the node firewall.

After looking it over and over, I then realizing that the nginx admission service node selectors were targeting the external IP addressed of my nodes, and translating the request from 443 via the service to 8443 on the external node IP I dump the live iptable state, so I didnt break any existing rules and added the required 8443 ACCEPT line then restored its config.

Dont forget if you have a main iptables file that loads on startup to add it too

```
# iptables-save > ~/iptables-current
# nano iptables-current  # add to the existing initial chain

  -A INPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 8443 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Ingress controller webhooks  (HTTPS)."

# iptables-restore < ~/iptables-current
# nano /etc/sysconfig/iptables     # add to the existing initial chain

  -A INPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 8443 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Ingress controller webhooks (HTTPS)."
```

another possible solution is to whitelist your nodes IP's (or scope) so you do not have to expose it outside the worker node pool and allow for any communication within and outside the k8s network)

same procedure as above, only using something like this

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -d 10.10.10.160/29 -j ACCEPT
```