# while installing ingress giving connection refused

Tags: kubernetes, virtual-machine, kubernetes-ingress, minikube, nginx-ingress

I installed ingress addon using `minikube addons enable ingress` on windows machine with virtualbox as driver (`--driver=virtualbox`).

**Minikube Version**

```sh
PS C:\Users\wv3cxq> minikube version
minikube version: v1.23.0
commit: 5931455374810b1bbeb222a9713ae2c756daee10
```

but when I try to install ingress, I am getting following error.

```sh
Error from server (InternalError): error when creating ".\\ingress.yaml": 
Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io": 
Post "https://ingress-nginx-controller-admission.ingress-nginx.svc:443/networking/v1/ingresses?timeout=10s": 
dial tcp 10.101.148.37:443: connect: connection refused
```

Ingress file

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-app-ingress
  labels:
    name: hello-app-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: hello-app-service
            port: 
              number: 8080
```

Comment: How exactly did you install `minikube`? Do you mean `--driver=virtualbox` or is it a linux VM with `minikube` inside? What version of `minikube` was installed? I need these details to attempt to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @moonkotte added info.

Comment: Thank you for adding details. I wasn't able to reproduce it with the same `minikube` version and `virtualbox` as a driver. Please refer to [this SO question ans answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61616203/nginx-ingress-controller-failed-calling-webhook), something should be helpful. Or you can try to use `--driver=docker` if you have `docker` installed on your machine.

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor still not